# Making a hole in a tree is okay? Or does it damages the tree?

Tags: botany

I am watching a TV series named "Treehouse Masters." What they do is make houses on trees or around it getting physical support from a big strong tree, like this:

[image]

But to make the support strong, they make a big hole in the trunk of a tree

[image]

Then they put a steel beam into it, like this:

[image]

In some cases, they make more than one hole. So, does this affect the tree in any way?

If anyone makes a hole that big or even bigger but doesn't fill it with any other thing(like the beam), will the tree heal itself?

I have heard that trunk is the most important part of a tree. So I am curious to know if this act is cruel towards the trees or not.

Comment: Trees don't have nerves or brains, so anthropomorphizing the effects of an action upon them as "cruel" is misguided. Yes, trees can be damaged by injuries that are too many or two large. However, they can also heal quite well if they are healthy overall. While the trunk is extremely important for holding up the tree, the bark and the layers just under it are the most important for delivering nutrients in between the leaves and roots. The inside wood of a tree is avascular, and essentially "dead", so the difference between a 5 cm deep hole and a 30 cm deep hole of the same diameter is small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can have a negative effect if parasites are able to take advantage of the holes in the tree.The bark is the first line of defense against parasites and making holes without covering them tend to have a negative effect.Furthermore, the bark also protects the plants against adverse weather conditions.